# Is there any way to attach more than one virtual network to a load balancer in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-load-balancer

I'm trying to create a load balancer and attach two virtual networks in order to have them in different zones(HA). I encountered the following error message when I try to add a second virtual network in the Backend pool section:

> A backend pool can only contain resources from one virtual network.

Is there any possibility to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to attach multiple virtual networks to a basic tier Azure load balancer - which I assume you are using. To achieve your desired infrastructure as described above, you would need to use a standard tier load balancer which supports availability zones and offers a 99.99% SLA (Service Level Agreement).

Comment: Hello! ok, I'll do it in this way, thanks for the confirmation :)